# R error with Knitr in Lyx

Tags: r, knitr, lyx

This is the code I am using, which runs fine in Rstudio

```
a1 <- matrix(c(1601, 162527, 510, 412368), nrow=2, byrow=T)  
chisq.test(a1, correct=F)
```

This is the error I get

```
! Undefined control sequence.  
<argument> ^^M##^^M##  Pearson'  
s Chi-squared test^^M##^^M## data:  a1^^M## X...  
l.356 \end{verbatim}  

The control sequence at the end of the top line  
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have  
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct  
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,  
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
```

It would work if I do

```
c1 <- chisq.test(a1, correct=F)
```

then call for the p-value using

```
c1$p.value
```

What is causing this problem?

Comment: just realized you asked the same question half a year ago...

Comment: I thought the other one has to do with significant codes, which one this doesn't have.

Comment: Both problems were caused by the single quotes. I can well understand that you did not realize this. I hope to close this question not because it is not a good question, but just to avoid duplicate answers.

Comment: @Yihui How do I close a question? Just delete it?

Comment: @SaberCN, yes that is one possibility. You as original poster should see an option to delete (or close) it.

Answer (score 2):

This is a known bug which has been fixed in the [development version](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/) (see [NEWS](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/blob/master/NEWS.md)). For now, you can install it from:

```
install.packages('knitr', repos = 'http://www.rforge.net/')
```